# How does GnuPG determine which compression algorithms are available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, gnupg

I am building an [AWS Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html) to provide the GnuPG `gpg` executable for my Lambda functions. In AWS Lambda, you can only package binary executables (`/opt/bin/`) and libraries (`/opt/lib`). I use a Docker container based on [amazon/aws-lambda-python:12](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-python).

In a simplified Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:12

WORKDIR /var/task

RUN dnf install -y rpmdevtools

RUN dnf download gnupg2
RUN rpmdev-extract gnupg2-*.rpm && rm gnupg2-*.rpm

RUN mkdir -p dist/bin && cp -t dist/bin/ -r ./*/usr/bin/*
RUN mkdir -p dist/lib && cp -t dist/lib/ -r ./*/usr/lib*/*
```

If I run `--version` inside the container, I get

```bash
$ gnupg2-2.3.7-1.amzn2023.0.4.x86_64/usr/bin/gpg --version | tail -n1
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

In a Lambda function with the created Lambda Layer attached, I get

```
Compression: Uncompressed
```

i.e. no supported compression.

I have tried to package countless other packages into the Lambda layer but without a change, still no compression supported. I even tried copying binaries from the container's `/usr/` itself but with no luck. Extra packages I tried (yes, I really am trying everything based on various experiments, even seemingly very unrelated packages):
amazon-rpm-config annobin-plugin-gcc binutils bzip2 cpp cracklib cyrus-sasl-lib dwz elfutils elfutils-debuginfod-client elfutils-libelf elfutils-libs file file-libs fonts-srpm-macros gcc gdbm-libs gnupg2 gnutls go-srpm-macros gzip libassuan libcurl-devel libgcrypt libgpg-error libksba libmodulemd libpwquality lz4 lzip lzo lzop nettle openldap openssl-devel pkgconf pkgconf-pkg-config python-srpm-macros rpm-build-libs xz xz-lzma-compat zip zlib zstd

All in all, I presume that GnuPG is using some other logic to determine which compression algorithms are available. I tried to dig through the source code but I cannot figure out what it could be. The best I can tell it is determined only at compile time ([[1]](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/g10/misc.c#L1374-L1389), [[2]](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/4dd4e9d2f1ac0d2a2add41e0e7ad2b328c117d55/configure.ac#L1465C2-L1524)) but in practice I see different outputs from the same binary, so there must be some other logic too.

Any idea how can I make GnuPG's `gpg` recognize installed compression algorithms? Is there some configuration or CLI option I can use?

Comment: Having the same problem with MWAA worker machines. After upgrade from Airflow 2.2.2 to Airflow 2.7.2 compression options have just gone. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @GeorgeHerolyants, Unfortunately I have not been able to find a solution to this. Would still be happy to hear if anyone knows how to get past this issue.